# How to mixin a Twitter Bootstrap utility class in my own custom SASS classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, utility

I have a custom class written in SASS:

```
.my-custom-container {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

I would like to mixin Bootstrap's `.p2` utility class, something like:

```
.my-customer-container {
    background-color: red;
    @mixin(p2);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are no mixins to do so because the spacing file of bootstrap is like this:

```
// stylelint-disable declaration-no-important

// Margin and Padding

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
      @each $size, $length in $spacers {

        .#{$abbrev}#{$infix}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
        .#{$abbrev}t#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
         #{$prop}-top: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}r#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
         #{$prop}-right: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}b#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
         #{$prop}-bottom: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}l#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-left: $length !important;
        }
      }
    }
    // Some special margin utils
    .m#{$infix}-auto { margin: auto !important; }
    .mt#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-top: auto !important;
    }
    .mr#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .mb#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-bottom: auto !important;
    }
    .ml#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-left: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that Bootstrap generates it's padding classes directly and doesn't use any mixin, so you can not reuse them.
You should write your own padding mixins or simply use $spacer variables.

```
.myClass {
    margin-top: $spacer*0.5;
}
```